# python - SyntaxError: invalid syntax after for loop block

Tags: python, pandas, pyqt5

I am trying to create a table in PyQt using the QTableView object. My data is stored in a `Pandas` dataframe.

Here is the code:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
import pandas as pd

cust_data = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\utkarsh.a.ranjan\\Documents\\final_datasets\\minimal_data.csv')

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(524, 424)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        self.tableView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 20, 411, 351))
        self.tableView.setMouseTracking(False)
        self.tableView.setObjectName("custData")
        self.tableView.setRowCount(cust_data.head().shape[0])
        self.tableView.setColumnCount(cust_data.head().shape[1])
        for i in range(cust_data.head().shape[0]):
            for j in range(cust_data.head().shape[0]):
                self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j, QTableWidgetItem(cust_data.iloc[i, j])
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 524, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    if not QtWidgets.QApplication.instance():
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    else:
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication.instance()
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

I am getting a syntax error in the line just after the for loops. I am failing to spot any syntax issues. If I remove the nested for loops, the error goes away. I am running the code on spyder IDE

Comment: self.tableWidget.setItem(i,j, QTableWidgetItem(cust_data.iloc[i, j]) misses a )

Comment: typo, You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of self.tableWidget.setItem(---

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a closing parenthesis at the end of `self.tableWidget.setItem(...`